# How to bind WebAPI Getall result to Select option using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Am trying to bind my WebAPI Get result to angular ng-option and am having a little difficulty in doing that, I will really appreciate any contribution you guys can give on this.

this is what i have done so far

here is my API

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var testcategories = _Service.GetTestCategories();
            if (testcategories != null)
            {
                return Ok(testcategories);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);

        }
    }
```

and now this is the Angular controller that am using to get the Test categories

```
vm.getTestCategories = function () {
        $scope._testCategories = TestCategory.query();
        console.log(_testCategories);
    };
```

this is the HTML am trying to bind

```
<div class="col-sm-9">

    <div class="input-group">
    <select name="TestCategory" class="form-control mb-10" id="TestCategory" ng-model="_test.TestCategory" ng-options="_testCategory.Id as _testCategory.Name for" on-blur-validation required><option ng-repeat="c in _categories._categories" value="{{c.Id}}">{{c.Name}}></option></select>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5a mb-10" onclick="toggle()"><span>Add</span> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button>
     </span>
     </div>

     <p class="help-block">
     <span ng-show="testForm.TestCategory.$invalid && !testForm.TestCategory.$pristine">Test Category is Required.</span>
      </p>
```

then i tried logging it to the console as you can see and it is working just fine. So how do i bind it to a select list in the font-end.

thank you for your opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard angular syntax for `select` element

```
<select name="TestCategory" class="form-control mb-10" id="TestCategory" 
        ng-model="_test.TestCategory"  
        ng-options="_testCategory.Id as _testCategory.Name for _testCategory in _testCategories" on-blur-validation required>
</select>
```

where `$scope._testCategories` your array of categories.
Then selected item id will be stored into the ng-model expression (`$scope._test.TestCategory` in provided example). If you want to select some item by default, setup `$scope._test.TestCategory` with id of that element.